# Structure of the monoid of maps up to homotopy

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

For a topological space $X$, what do we know about the monoid $[X,X]$ : continuous maps up to homotopy ? For example, what is the structure of $[RP^2,RP^2]$ ? $RP^2$ is the projective space of dimension $2$. I guessed it might be the same as for the universal cover $S^2$ so $\mathbb{Z}$ or a semi-direct product with $\pi_1(RP^2)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: When your space is an Eilenberg-MacLane space for a group G there is a ring structure that is isomorphic to Hom(G,G).

Comment: Is $Hom(G,G)$ a ring when $G$ is non-abelian ?

Comment: G should be taken to be abelian.

Comment: I’m not positive, but there might be a ring structure if G is free. It at least forms an abelian group because free groups are the cogroup objects in Grp, but I don’t know the specifics and if composition of maps interacts well with the structure.

Comment: What is your question? Only the special case $X = RP^2$?